# How to redirect from a form using HTTP_REFERER

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a search field that yields a list of records. Each record on that list has an "edit" button that opens the record within an update form:

```
#views.py

def updateEntry(request, id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostEntryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = PostEntry.objects.get(pk = id))
        if request.POST.get('delete'):
            instance = PostEntry.objects.get(pk=id)
            instance.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    else:
        form = PostEntryForm(instance = PostEntry.objects.get(pk = id))
        tpl = 'assetpost/postupdate_form.html'
        variables = RequestContext(request, {'form':form })
        return render_to_response(tpl, variables)
```

template:

```
#postupdate_form.html:

<div class="container tmarg">
    <div class="row">

        <form name="PostEntryForm" action=""  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="well">
                      {{ form|crispy }}
                  </div>
              </div>
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

and basic url confs:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^newpostpage/', PageCreate.as_view(), name='postpage'),
    url(r'^create-entry/', createEntry, name='createEntry'),
    url(r'^updatepage/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', PageUpdate.as_view(), name='update_page'),
    url(r'^update-entry/(?P<id>\w+)/$', updateEntry, name='updateEntry'),
    url(r'^multipost/', multipost, name='multipost'),

)
```

as suggested by the "request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')" declarations in the view code, the behavior I'm attempting to produce is:

user types in the search parameters; gets a list of records; clicks on an individual record and opens it in update form; modifies or deletes it - **and is redirected back to the list from which he came.** it's the redirect that I'm having difficulty with.
As it stands now, clicking "delete" or "submit" in the update form does perform the delete or modify on the record, but then throws a "matching query does not exist." error when attempting the redirect.
I've tried using the HTTP_REFERER in the form action attribute -and it does redirect back to the list - but before any action on the record is taken, leaving the db unchanged. Can anybody point me in the direction of rectifying this?

Using Django 1.8 and Python 3.4

Comment: Here is my guess: When you do an `instance.delete()`, your `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` is probably pointing to the deleted object, which is the cause of the issue. You might want to redirect the user to, lets say the list page

Comment: I think you're right. On further debugging, the submit action doesn't yield the error, it simply redirects right back to the modified object. Problem is, the list page is a search result; in the dev, looks something like "localhost:8000/main/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=pMsawKMhganH71tCf7VuzhfvT9kpFxzt&query=GOOG&search=search" That's why I was using a 'HTTP_REFERER' to capture it.

Comment: You could use a hidden `next` field in the form, which could be used to keep track of the redirect URL.

Comment: not sure how that would work.

Comment: actually, thinking a bit about it, I think that might work. Taking a crack at it. Thanks.

Comment: @kjarsenal, could you please post your solution? I am facing the same use case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually pretty easy to resolve. I'm sure there are many ways to do it but mine was as follows:

I first included a hidden field in my form and gave it a name attribute 'URL':

```
<div style="display:hidden;">
    <input type="text" name="URL" id="refURL" /> 
</div>
```

then I used a bit of js to capture the referrer url and assign it to the hidden form field:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var refURL=document.referrer;
     var target=document.getElementById('refURL');
     target.value=refURL
 </script>
```

and finally I modified my view to pull the URL from the POST data and use it in my HTTP Response:

```
#views.py

def updateEntry(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
        ...
        ...
    if form.is_valid():
        URL = request.POST.get('URL')
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(URL)
```